# Can we guarantee that Android's SpeechRecognizer does not send data to Google?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, privacy

I'm trying to implement Android's SpeechRecognizer feature. Due to privacy constraints of my company, the data must explicitly ***not leave the device***.

So far:

- I've implemented the SpeechRecognizer class by using the `SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer`method. When I tried it without internet, it just worked fine!
  However, there's not guarantee as far as I see that Google won't send the data when online, if not for transcription, then for improving their Audio training data..
- `SpeechRecognizer.createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer` - This is available from Android 12 and on. Let's say I don't mind. However, it only works in specific devices, ie. Pixel 6 but not even in Pixel 4a.
- `putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, true)` - This didn't work either. It keeps giving me the error: `ERROR_NO_MATCH`, in any device that I've tried.

So that leaves us with plain `SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer` and my implementation is like this:

```
var recognizerIntent: Intent? = null
        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(applicationContext)) {
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(applicationContext)

            val listener = MySpeechRecognitionListener(scopeProvider, lifecycleScope, {
                ...
            }
            sr.setRecognitionListener(listener)
            recognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).apply {
                putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH)
            }
            sr.startListening(recognizerIntent)
} else {...}
```

Question:
Can we somehow guarantee that Android's SpeechRecognizer does not send data to Google?

Comment: If it is Android, I would assume anything and everything would get sent to Google. You could always ask them.

Comment: Also note that Google would not be your only concern. Device manufacturers could also modify how `SpeechRecognizer` works.

Comment: @Surajkumar_cse the answer is that we're unsure so like Bib said, we cannot guarantee it. I even went ahead in a forum by Google and I got the same answer so I moved along using a different solution. (Vosk library)

Comment: can you share the link of that google forum?

Comment: @Surajkumar_cse Ok yeah found it: https://support.google.com/android/thread/137964238/can-we-guarantee-that-android-s-speechrecognizer-does-not-send-data-to-google?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public static SpeechRecognizer createSpeechRecognizer (Context context, 
                ComponentName serviceComponent)
```

specifying a `serviceComponent` that is open source, so that you can verify that it does not send data to Google.

I don't see any other solution, i.e. I'm not aware of any Android API flags like `DONT_SEND_DATA_TO_GOOGLE`.

Answer (score -1):

you could ensure that internet connection (wifi, cell network, etc) is disabled during the recognizing however that does not guarantee that the recognized speech isn't recorded/cached and sent to google later when there is a network connection.

Comment: yeah exactly. They might do it for "improving their voice services" later in batches